# Convert .mov files to Home Theater compatible MP4

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg, transcode, winff, home-theatre

I have bunch of mov files and I want to play them on my Sony DVD Home Theater (Xvid/HDMI capable) but I cannot. I have tried different configuration in WinFF (ffmpeg frontend) but does not work. The player complains video frame rate is not supported.

Here is some information from `mplayer`:

```
Detected file format: QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 format (libavformat)
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang eng
VIDEO:  [H264]  720x576  24bpp  29.970 fps  1249.0 kbps (152.5 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 major_brand: isom
 minor_version: 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
 creation_time: 2006-12-22 01:43:44
 encoder: Lavf53.21.1
Load subtitles in .
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
[ass] auto-open
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Asking decoder to use 2 threads if supported.
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 112.0 kbit/7.29% (ratio: 14000->192000)
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
A:   0.0 V:   0.0 A-V:  0.000 ct:  0.000   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [xv] 720x576 => 768x576 Planar YV12 
A:  44.1 V:  44.1 A-V:  0.001 ct:  0.000   0/  0  3%  3%  0.5% 0 0 

Exiting... (Quit)
```

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to install & use **Ffmpeg** not WinFF.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Once Ffmpeg is installed, open Terminal and paste the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -sameq output.mp4
```

Where input.mov & output.mp4  Change the filenames accordingly.

That command encodes the video into an **.mp4** format but keeps the same quality as the original.

Comment: The issue is my player complains frame rate is not supported. I'm not that much good in video arena and so I dont know what to do!
BTW I use ffmpeg with WinFF front end

Comment: Running the command mentioned above with apparently a newer version of ffmpeg led me to executing the following: ffmpeg -i input.mov -q:a 0 -q:v 0 -strict -2 output.mp4

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mencoder

> Mencoder is a companion program to the MPlayer media player that can
>   be used to encode or transform any audio or video stream that MPlayer
>   can read.<sup>1</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install mencoder
```

Or you can install it from thr Ubuntu Software Center

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MEncoder)</sup>

Comment: Will it play encoded files on my Sony Home Theater?

Comment: I have to say yes.  Take a look at [This](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/projects.html)

Comment: so how do I use it? (pls don't say mencoder --help I just need full commandline!)

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg has been replaced in Trusty by avconv, in the libav-tools package. See:

- [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/432542/57576)

The `sameq` option has been removed.  For advice see:

- [Ffmpeg, avconv and sameq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349009/ffmpeg-avconv-and-sameq)

Comment: `ffmpeg` returned in 15.04.

Comment: 15.04 is not LTS though, so most folks are not on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use Curlew : [Curlew:- 32 or 64 ubuntu WebBlog](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2014/01/install-curlew-ubuntu-13-10/)