# How to Convert All The .MOV Videos To .MP4 in folder

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, mp4, mov

using ubuntu 14.04 i am a newbie can anyone help how to easily convert all the .mov files in my /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/ctkdonline_com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08 folder need to convert all the .MOV files to .MP4 please help :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285542/convert-mov-files-to-home-theater-compartible-mp4 should have all the info you need; just need to add a bash loop to those commands. There is also a  gui option: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/ffmulticonverter-is-now-available-for.html

Answer (score 7):

Here are the proper methods:

## Stream copy

If you simply want to re-mux instead of re-encode, and if the input streams are compatible with MP4, you can just [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy). It is fast and will preserve quality:

```
mkdir out
for f in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -movflags +faststart out/"${f%.mov}.mp4"; done
```

## Re-encode

If you want to re-encode:

```
mkdir out
for f in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -movflags +faststart out/"${f%.mov}.mp4"; done
```

Adjust `-crf` and `-preset` according to your needs as described in [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). Or just rely on the defaults if it looks acceptable (`-crf 23 -preset medium` will be used if you omit these options).

For audio info see [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

## Stream copy one stream, re-encode another

Of course you can do both if you prefer:

```
mkdir out
for f in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart out/"${f%.mov}.mp4"; done
```

## Getting `ffmpeg`

Since you used the `ffmpeg` tag I'll assume that's what you want to use. Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't provide `ffmpeg`, but even if it did I would recommend using a recent build since development is very active. You have 4 main options as described in [FFmpeg on Ubuntu Trusty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158824/1109017) (static build or PPA is easiest).